# How to Multichoice Options That Appears When Clicking Single Chocie in Android

Tags: java, android, multiple-choice, multichoiceitems, dropdownchoice

I want something like this. There could be passive multichoice buttons below all of the single choices. It doesn't matter. Is that possible?

[Single and Multiple Choice Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuF3A.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to show a bit of what you have tried so that those who are capable of helping can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control visibility of every view with view.setVisibility(View.Visible or View.Gone). Set click listener on single choice button and use that method to show container layout with radio buttons.

```
chkIos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {        
    if (v.isChecked()) {
        multiChoiceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        multiChoiceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

});
```

To build a layout like on your picture you can combine RadioGroup with LinearLayout under each RadioButton, in this way:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I added a picture. I get it how to make visible or gone but I don't know how to list below singlechoice

Comment: I can not change the view of dialogue after clicking on my trigger button. It crashes. There is no meaning of changing the view before appearing it. Because I have to get value, if the single button is checked or else.